# Amdahl's Law in "C++ Concurrency in Action"

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I'm doing a BSc thesis on multithreading and one bibliography reference is "C++ Concurrency in Action" by Anthony Williams. It helped me a lot in using std threads, however there is one thing that I'm not sure about. The formula mentioned for Amdahl's law is

> P(N) = 1 /( f + ( 1 - f )/ N )

Whereas all other sources I found give:

> P(N) = 1 / ( 1 - f + f / N )

In both cases P is performance gain factor, f is a constant fraction of "serial", independent sections in [0, 1] and N is a number of processors (natural number).

Even the horizontal asymptote of the function in the first case is 1/f and in the second one it is 1/(1 - f). Is it an error or did I understand it wrong?

Comment: Isn't this off-topic for SO?

Comment: @Zeta Yes. Way _too broad_ / _unclear_.

Comment: a specific programming problem: for threading, it is specific programming problem

Comment: a software algorithm: it is describing general software architecture and behavior of algorithms(threads in this case)

Comment: a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development: yes it is answerable, yes it is unique to software development

Comment: I bet this seems to be a question that fits the stackoverflow questions guidelines. The only problem is, that it does not fit everybody's knowledge...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first, f is the fraction of serial code, and in the second, f is the fraction of parallel.

If you plug (1-f) into f in either equation, you will get the other